# I can't get the output right

Tags: javascript

```
for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    for (var i = 10; i >= j; i--) {
        document.write(i * 10 + ' ')
    }
    document.write('<BR>');
}
```

I've been trying to get this output:

```
100 90 80 70 50 40 30 20 10 
-----------------
90 90 70 60 50 40 30 20 10 
-----------------
80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10 
-----------------
70 60 50 40 30 20 10 
-----------------
60 50 40 30 20 10 
-----------------
50 40 30 20 10 
-----------------
40 30 20 10 
-----------------
30 20 10
-----------------
20 10
-----------------
10
-----------------
```

But all that i get is this:

```
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10 
-----------------
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 
-----------------
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30  
-----------------
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 
-----------------
100 90 80 70 60 50 
-----------------
100 90 80 70 60 
-----------------
100 90 80 70 
-----------------
100 90 80
-----------------
100 90
-----------------
100
-----------------
```

Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 for (var j = 10; j >= 1; --j) {
     for (var i = j * 10; i >= 10; i -= 10) {
         document.write(i + ' ')
     }
     document.write('<BR>');
 }
```

> Reverse loop is best fit in your case to improve understandability &
>   performance.

Comment: Not really satisfying the expected output (as it's not printing, for example, _100_ in every row for the first column).

Comment: I think you are looking at actual output not the expected output. He don't want 100 in first column of every row. :)

Comment: Doh, my appologies @Vijay - I need my morning coffee

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 for ( var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for ( var j = 11; j >i; j--) {
            document.write((j-i) * 10 + ' ');
        }
        document.write('<BR>');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below:

```
for(j=100;j>=10;j-=10){
  for(i=j;i>=10; i-=10){
    document.write(i + ' ');
  }
  document.write('<BR>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
      var k= 10;
   for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
   for (var i = k; i >0; i--) {
    document.write(i * 10 + ' ')
   }
   document.write('<BR>');
   k--;
  }
```